# Can't import Django model - ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: python, django, sqlite, import

I want to process some data from the database in `Django`. The thing is that it raises some exception when it tries to import `models`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

from uploading import models

# lang = models.Languages.objects.get(language_shortcut='EN')
# print lang.price_per_word
```

I've already do migrations and insert some data using `Django admin`.

**SETTINGS.PY:**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

This is the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Milano/PycharmProjects/mysite/uploading/scripts/calculator.py", line 3, in <module>
    from uploading import models
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\mysite\uploading\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Languages(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\mysite\uploading\models.py", line 4, in Languages
    language = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1081, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 161, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Whats wrong with that code?

Answer (score 1):

You don't show exactly what you're doing but it seems that you are running a standalone script. In order to do that you need to configure Django, as the error states - see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage) for an example of how to do that.

Note however that this sort of thing is usually better written as a [custom manage.py script](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Comment: Daniel thanks, I'm very new to Django so I don't know exactly what I have to do. My app is called uploadings and there is a directory inside it which is called scripts where I want to store the scripts. This script should compute let's say number of words in text retrieved from form and compare it with data in the database. I want to compute that each time user uploads some text using a form. I've tried the thing from docs but I can't import from uploadings import myapp_defaults (or uploadings_defaults). There is no such file or module.

Comment: You don't need to use defaults, that's only if you want to override some things. See the previous section on setting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE. But as I said above, all this is *much* simpler if you write it as a custom manage.py script.